# Administrator elevation in Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, administrator

I'm trying write a script that uses a gui to run proprietary powershell scripts in a single button. However, almost all the scripts require administrator access to get the scripts. I'm trying to open powershell_ise via subprcess.Popen as an administrator.

Would it be possible to do something like:

```
a = subprocess.Popen(["runas","/user:Administrator","path to powershell_ise","script",stdout=sys.out)
a.communicate()
```

where it then asks for administrator credentials to open ps_ise as an admin where at the top it displays (Administrator: Windows PowerShell ISE).

I tried having a bunch of conditionals, but it seemed to only run python.exe as an admin not powershell. If anyone has any ideas i'd really appreciate it.

EDIT: I guess I'm trying to run a target path via shortcut like:

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\runas.exe /env /noprofile /user:ADMINACC
>   "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
>   -noprofile -command \"start-process powershell_ise -verb RunAs\""

but within the subprocess.Popen function

Comment: Could `shell=True` parameter help?

Comment: Doesn't seem to help :\